# Foreign currency losing value -- can I report this as a loss for tax purposes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-exchange, losses

I live in the U.S., and I have a savings bank account in Ukraine.

The money on that account were in UAH (Ukrainian Hryvnia), which lost ~50% of its value during 2014. This means the amount on my account decreased 2x when converted to USD.

The question is:

Can I somehow report this as a loss (investment loss?) to IRS (to decrease the amount of taxes I should pay for 2014)?

Note: I've reported this account properly to the IRS before 2014.

Thanks.

Comment: If it was the other way around, would you be asking about reporting gain?

Comment: Apparently, you should..http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/43254/capital-gains-on-foreign-investment

Comment: @User58220 no, I'm not so sure. In that question, the topic was *bonds*, not cash. In the case of the OP the cash was probably earned in Ukraine before he moved.

Comment: @littleadv Well, this is tax system -- so everything is possible :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a US expat with savings in multiple currencies considered to be investing in the non-USD currency?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/44853/is-a-us-expat-with-savings-in-multiple-currencies-considered-to-be-investing-in)

Answer (score 2):

This loss would be unrealized and, assuming you're a cash-basis tax-payer, you would not be able to take a loss on your 2014 tax return. This is similar to if you held a stock that lost 50% of its value. You wouldn't be able to claim this loss until you finally sold it.

The link that User58220 posted may come into play if you converted your UAH back to USD.